# What should be done to do multiple order by?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to sort by chart_num and DATE. However, the following results are printed out when aligned:

in this my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT id, chart_num, chart_name, MIN(DATE) AS DATE, amount, (COUNT(*) = 2) AS result, card_check
    FROM (
        (
            SELECT id, hpd.chart_num AS chart_num, hpd.chart_name AS chart_name, hpd.visit AS DATE, card_amount_received AS amount, card_check_modify AS card_check
                ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY card_amount_received ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
            FROM hospital_payment_data hpd
            WHERE store_mbrno = '135790' AND card_amount_received > 0
        ) 
        UNION ALL (
            SELECT id, ncd. chart_num AS chart_num, ncd. chart_name AS chart_name, DATE_FORMAT(ncd.tranDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATA, amount, card_check_result AS card_check
                ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY amount ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
            FROM noti_card_data ncd
            WHERE (mbrNo = '135790' OR mbrNo = '135791') AND cmd ='승인'
        )
    ) X
    GROUP BY amount, seqnum 
    ORDER BY result DESC
) a 
ORDER BY a.DATE DESC
```

[image]

The result I want is that the NULL value goes back to the latest DATE, and if there is a chart_num, I want to sort it in order of chart_num and DATE.

Comment: `ORDER BY a.DATE, coalesce(a.chart_num,-1)`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Is chart_num a VARCHAR, as it looks like in the output?  Or is it numeric but the output UI is crappy for not right-justifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like I'm missing something else with this question, but you can separate columns in the `ORDER BY` with a comma. It's not clear from your text whether you want dates grouped within the same chart_num or charts grouped within the same date, but if I guessed wrong you can just swap it.

Also, the `ORDER BY result DESC` is completely extra. It adds nothing to the results, and by removing it we can get rid of a whole level of nesting.

```
SELECT id, chart_num, chart_name, MIN(DATE) AS DATE, amount, (COUNT(*) = 2) AS result, card_check
FROM (
    (
        SELECT id, hpd.chart_num AS chart_num, hpd.chart_name AS chart_name, hpd.visit AS DATE, card_amount_received AS amount, card_check_modify AS card_check
            ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY card_amount_received ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
        FROM hospital_payment_data hpd
        WHERE store_mbrno = '135790' AND card_amount_received > 0
    ) 
    UNION ALL (
        SELECT id, ncd.chart_num, ncd.chart_name, DATE_FORMAT(ncd.tranDate,'%Y-%m-%d'), amount, card_check_result
            ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY amount ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
        FROM noti_card_data ncd
        WHERE mbrNo IN ('135790', '135791') AND cmd ='승인'
    )
) X
GROUP BY amount, seqnum 
ORDER BY MIN(DATE), coalesce(chart_num,-1), result DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont order by result in the inner union all query.
Sort by chart_num and date in place of result.

So in place of

```
Order by result desc
```

use this:

```
Order by chart_num desc, DATE desc
```

Or,

in outer main query:

in place of

```
Order by a.DATE DESC
```

use

```
Order by a.chart_num desc, a.DATE desc
```

Hope it helps.!